# Need to capture hive query from application id

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop-yarn, apache-tez

I want to find the hive query from application id, I know that in TEZ view I can see the query, but i want to know if there is any api which I can use to find query from application id from command line or through curl command?

Comment: Well, with application id, you can at least do `yarn logs -applicationId <id>`, but I don't know if that gives the query

Comment: @cricket_007 No this will give logs only, query is not present in this.

Comment: Ideally the query would be in the logs somewhere. Maybe not the YARN logs, but definitely the Hive Server logs... You would need to use something like Fluentbit / Filebeat to extract this data into a searchable / aggregatable format